# Swapping Global XAML Styles / Themes

Tags: c#, windows-8, styles, winrt-xaml

My UI is defined by a set of styles.

I would like to give the user to choose from two families of styles.

How do I swap out global styles in code behind?

Comment: Custom Themes are not supported (at least know that much) http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/ba77cedb-b90b-49a2-af00-aba9e14dcef2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pay close attention to dependencies so that a resource doesn't try to reference another resource that is not yet defined.  See the section on [Merged Dictionaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh968442.aspx) to see what is loaded when.  Also, You will have to move all resources from App.xaml into your generic resource dictionary because they will be cleared when you reset your application resources to your new merged dictionary.

The updates only seem to take effect when the elements are recreated, so a navigation is required to apply the changes.

```
private void LoadStyles(StyleType styleType)
{
    ResourceDictionary merged = new ResourceDictionary();
    ResourceDictionary generic = new ResourceDictionary();
    ResourceDictionary theme = new ResourceDictionary();

    generic.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:/Common/StandardStyles.xaml");

    switch (styleType)
        {
            default:
            case StyleType.Custom1: { theme.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:/Common/AppStyles-Custom1.xaml"); break; }
            case StyleType.Custom2: { theme.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:/Common/AppStyles-Custom2.xaml"); break; }
            case StyleType.Custom3: { theme.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:/Common/AppStyles-Custom3.xaml"); break; }
        }

    merged.MergedDictionaries.Add(generic);
    merged.MergedDictionaries.Add(theme);

    App.Current.Resources = merged;

    //this.ApplyTemplate(); <- doesn't seem to reapply resources to layout tree
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this but the theme doesn't get applied unless I set it in App.xaml.cs. If I set it anywhere else it doesn't work. Is there a way to have it applied immediately?

Answer (score 3):

The following articles might help:

- [WPF Themes and Skins Engine](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22575/WPF-Themes-and-Skins-Engine)
- [Creating a Skinned User Interface in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19782/Creating-a-Skinned-User-Interface-in-WPF)

In general you need to replace the `App.Resources.MergedDictionaries` in runtime with the new resources from probably another assembly and reapply template at list at the level of `MainWindow`, be sure to have `DynamicResource` in your style assignements. The following algorithm may help you:

1. Clean `App.Resources.MergedDictionaries`
2. Fill `App.Resources.MergedDictionaries` with new set of `ResourceDictionary`
3. Reapply window template with `mainWindow.ApplyTemplate();`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Its possible.  I played with this some time ago, and got it to work.  If I find code I will share